# Embedded tomcat using Cargo plugin for a Spring boot 2.0.0.M3 Application

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat8, maven-cargo

We are trying to migrate existing application from

- Spring Boot v1.4.6.RELEASE
- tomcat7-maven-plugin
- Runtime as Embedded tomcat 7

To the new versions

- Spring boot v2.0.0.M3
- cargo-maven2-plugin
- Embedded tomcat 8.5.5 Runtime

This is consistently giving me below error during the application startup.

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] SEVERE: Error during ServletContainerInitializer processing
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:158)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5178)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.accessibleConstructor(Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:155)
```

When i tried to debug this piece of code I see at times its JerseyWebApplicationInitializer or Our custom Application Initializer is resulting in this error. When I searched about error it seems its arising out of version mismatch but I cant find any issue using maven dependency tree.

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ app-dim ---
[INFO] com.company.app:app-dim:war:0.3.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.company.app:app-dim-gemfire-function:jar:0.3.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- com.company.app:app-dim-batch-services:jar:0.3.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.company.app:app-common-logging:jar:0.3.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.0.0.RC3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.0.0.RC3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.0.0.RC3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.perf4j:perf4j:jar:0.9.16:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.0.RC3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.0.RC3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.0.0.RC3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.0.RC3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.0.RC3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.0.RC3:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.el:el-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.company.app:app-common-config:jar:0.3.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.company.app:app-common-messaging:jar:0.3.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:jar:2.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework.ws:spring-xml:jar:2.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-support:jar:2.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.company.app:app-common-gemfire-jca:jar:0.3.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.company.app:app-common-crypto:jar:0.3.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.0.RC3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.0.0.M3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.0.0.RC2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.0.M3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.0.pr4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.0.pr4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.0.0.RC3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.0.0.RC3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.0.0.RC3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services:jar:2.0.0.M3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.0.M3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:cdi1.0:15.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.5.16:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-gemfire:jar:2.0.0.RC2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.0.0.RC2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.pivotal.gemfire:geode-core:jar:9.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.stephenc.findbugs:findbugs-annotations:jar:1.3.9-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jgroups:jgroups:jar:3.6.10.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- it.unimi.dsi:fastutil:jar:7.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.resource:javax.resource-api:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:4.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.github.lukehutch:fast-classpath-scanner:jar:2.0.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.pivotal.gemfire:geode-common:jar:9.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.pivotal.gemfire:geode-json:jar:9.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.pivotal.gemfire:geode-cq:jar:9.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.pivotal.gemfire:geode-lucene:jar:9.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:6.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:6.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:jar:6.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:jar:6.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-sandbox:jar:6.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.pivotal.gemfire:geode-wan:jar:9.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0.pr4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- org.testng:testng:jar:6.10:test
[INFO] |  \- com.beust:jcommander:jar:1.48:test
[INFO] +- com.company.app:app-common-utils:jar:0.3.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-csv:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:5.0.0.RC3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:5.0.0.RC3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:5.0.0.RC3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] +- javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] +- com.company.app:app-common-sequence:jar:0.3.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.oracle.ojdbc:ojdbc:jar:7.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.company.app:app-common-domain:jar:0.3.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- com.company.app:app-common-data-gemfire:jar:0.3.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- com.company.app:app-common-services:jar:0.3.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- com.company.app:app-common-security:jar:0.3.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.0.0.M3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.0.0.M3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.0.0.M3:compile
[INFO] +- com.company.app:app-common-batch-utils:jar:0.3.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.session:spring-session:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.company.app:app-test-lib:jar:0.3.1-SNAPSHOT:test
[INFO] |  \- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.5:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.0.54-beta:test
[INFO] |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.6.14:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] +- com.mockrunner:mockrunner:jar:0.3.1:test
[INFO] +- de.danielbechler:java-object-diff:jar:0.94:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.2.21.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.2.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.2.21.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.0.0.M3:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.0.0.RC3:test
[INFO] +- org.jxls:jxls:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-jexl:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.jxls:jxls-poi:jar:1.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.12:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.12:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |           \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.javers:javers-core:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.picocontainer:picocontainer:jar:2.14.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:jar:4.0.0.M3:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.batch:javax.batch-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-infrastructure:jar:4.0.0.M3:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:3.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:jar:136:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar:136:compile
[INFO] |  +- jfree:jcommon:jar:1.0.15:compile
[INFO] |  +- jfree:jfreechart:jar:1.0.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] |  \- eclipse:jdtcore:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:2.4.6:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.github.jnr:jnr-ffi:jar:2.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.github.jnr:jffi:jar:1.2.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.github.jnr:jffi:jar:native:1.2.10:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-util:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.github.jnr:jnr-x86asm:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.web:el-impl:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] +- javax.el:javax.el-api:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.8.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jcl:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.0.0.M3:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.16:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.16:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.16:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-all:jar:5.14.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.18:runtime
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: unfortunately not. Later i shifted my focus to some other task as our plan to migrate on Spring boot 2.0 went on hold :-)